# NoSuchMethodError writing Avro object to HDFS using Builder

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hdfs, avro

I'm getting this exception when writing an object to HDFS:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/avro/Schema;
        at com.blah.SomeType.<clinit>(SomeType.java:10)
```

The line it is referencing in the generated code is this:

```
public class SomeType extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse ..........
```

And the call in my code is this:

```
val someTypeBuilder = SomeType.newBuilder()
      .setSomeField("some value")
      // set a whole load of other fields
```

Calling `newBuilder()` in test code causes no issues at all.

The jar is being run on an HDFS node using the `hadoop jar` command.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[org.apache.avroSchema.Parser.parse(String s, String... more)](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.Parser.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) was not introduced until Avro 1.7.5.  Notice its absence in the [1.7.4 Schema.Parser documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.4/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.Parser.html).  Either update your HDFS node to use a more recent version of Avro, or join the Strings yourself like how the [current 1.7 version of Schema](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/branch-1.7/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.java#L974) does and use the method that takes a single String instead:

```
public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse(String.join("", prevArg1, prevArg2));
```

EDIT:
I've never tried upgrading Avro on a Hadoop installation, but I would guess you could probably just find the jars and replace them manually if it's a minor version upgrade.

```
~/dev/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1$ find . -name '*avro*.jar'
./share/hadoop/tools/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar
./share/hadoop/httpfs/tomcat/webapps/webhdfs/WEB-INF/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar
./share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar
./share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar
./share/hadoop/kms/tomcat/webapps/kms/WEB-INF/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar
```

Try downloading [Avro 1.7.7](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.7/avro-1.7.7.jar) and replacing all those found jars with downloaded one.  I would also back up the Hadoop installation in case it goes awry.

Comment: Ok this could be it. My HDFS node is using Avro 1.7.4 when running the jar. Is there an easy way to update the shared jars on HDFS nodes? Or is it a new Hadoop install?

Comment: @jimmy_terra I edited my post with a suggested way of upgrading Avro.  Can't guarantee it will work for your app though.

Comment: I'd suggest downgrading your build (Gradle/Maven/whatever) to match the version in the environment you are executing in (at least until you upgrade your cluster).  The correct way to upgrade your cluster is dependent on your setup and vendor (if applicable).

Comment: I'll award you the bounty, thanks for your help. Interestingly, v1.7.7 seems to divide up large schemas into multiple strings. In this case, my schema is large and in the JSON string, it arbitrarily introduces a comma close to the end, hence the attempt to call the `parse(String s, String... more)` version of parse. I'm not sure if this is deliberate behaviour by Avro or a bug.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if splitting large schema strings is intended behaviour for Avro, because it clear breaks affects compatibility.

Comment: this error also happened when I had 2 different versions of avro in my project.