# Incorrect dependency version when uploading to Hadoop cluster

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to run a MapReduce job on a Hadoop cluster using Azure HDInsight. In my .jar I have the following dependencies (from `mvn dependency:tree`):

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:hadoop1:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:1.8.1:compile
```

When I compile the jar and run it on my machine, everything works. But when I run it on an HDInsight cluster I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/avro/Schema;
        at org.foo.bar.MyClass.<clinit>(MyClass.java:9)
        at org.foo.bar.Sample.main(Sample.java:242)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.\
java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:158)
```

This is a dependency version conflict - `org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse` is only defined in avro version 1.7.5 (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687550/nosuchmethoderror-writing-avro-object-to-hdfs-using-builder)) so it must be that on the cluster there is a different version of the package being used. But I was under the impression that the dependencies are packaged within the jar file, so I'm confused why that's happening. Why is this the case and how do I fix it (or at least inspect the issue further, for example by ssh-ing into the cluster and examining the files in there)?

For reference here is the dependencies section of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.1</version>
  <classifier>hadoop1</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-examples</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you try to use Avro 1.7.4 version and check whether it solves ?

Comment: That doesn't compile.

Comment: Check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687550/nosuchmethoderror-writing-avro-object-to-hdfs-using-builder

Comment: Yes, I linked to that in my question. Unfortunately I can't just upgrade avro on the cluster because I'm automatically provisioning and deleting the cluster daily.

Comment: What do you use to include the dependencies into the jar? If you just build a plain jar with e.g. `clean install`, dependencies will _not_ be included.

Comment: `mvn clean package`

Answer (score 0):

The [Maven JAR Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/index.html) (bound to the `package` phase by default) will *not* include dependencies:

> create a jar file for **your** project classes

There are other plugins to achieve such: [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/index.html), [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Also, this is not a [dependency version conflict](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html), since you're not using the same dependency with two different versions (at build time) but you're using one, most probably older version (on the server) at runtime that doesn't yet contain the method you refer to.

To include `org.apache.avro:avro-mapred` in your JAR declare e.g. the Shade Plugin with:

```xml
<artifactSet>
  <includes>
    <include>org.apache.avro:avro-mapred</include>
  </includes>
</artifactSet>
```

to include all of its classes/resources or add:

```xml
<filters>
  <filter>
    <artifact>org.apache.avro:avro-mapred</artifact>
    <includes>
      <include>org/apache/avro/Schema*</include>
    </includes>
  </filter>
</filters>
```

to include just the `Schema` and its nested classes.